# Change JPEG file DPI header in Node.js

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, jpeg, puppeteer

I have a file (for example JPEG size 1588 × 2244px). It's generated by `puppeteer` (but `phantomjs` also generate `72 DPI` screenshot). When I save this image into a file with `.jpeg` extension and I use  macOS General Info I see:

[image]

As you can see it has `72 DPI` set in metadata, but I want to use file with `300 DPI`. I know, that in digital it doesn't change anything - it's property for printing, but I don't want to explain to each customer that this file could be print in `300 DPI`.

When I use Gimp and `Image > Print Size`

[image]

I can change the DPI, and export a picture again. And now it has `300 DPI` in `General Info` window.

[image]

I try to do it in Node.JS server, but I found few options to change this property on `.PNG` pictures, but anyone is working for `.JPEG` files.

I think that the most accurate option is to use method `changeDpiDataUrl` from this library:
https://github.com/shutterstock/changeDPI/blob/master/src/index.js
But when I put my image as `base64image`, after a `split` operation I have the `array` with 1 element only - I think that this is body, so I don't have format property (at 63 line).

Anybody meet this problem before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the library [`piexifjs`](https://github.com/hMatoba/piexifjs) to change the EXIF data of an image. The library only changes the meta data (called EXIF), not the image itself.

**Code Sample**

The following code uses the [API](https://piexifjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html) to read the EXIF data of an image, change it and create a new buffer from the changed data.

```js
const piexif = require("piexifjs");

// get the image buffer from puppeteer or from disk
const imageBuffer = /* ... */

// convert buffer to string and load it
const imageString = imageBuffer.toString('binary');
const exif = piexif.load(imageString);

// change resolution
exif['0th'][piexif.ImageIFD.XResolution] = [300,1];
exif['0th'][piexif.ImageIFD.YResolution] = [300,1];

// generate new EXIF data
const newExifDump = piexif.dump(exif);

// generate new image
const newData = piexif.insert(newExifDump, imageString);
const jpgBuffer = new Buffer(newData, "binary");

// write to file or use buffer
// ...
```

Be aware, that I have not used the library myself, nor have I tested the code.

Comment: Note that JPEG files can contain resolution information in both EXIF metadata and also "regular" JPEG metadata. This only modifies EXIF data, not the other.  It depends on the application which DPI value it uses.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is another alternative to the answer given by @thomasdondorf.

The resolution/density can be set easily using JavaScript standard image processing library [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) by [withMetadata](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-output#withmetadata) function.

Simple example:

```js
// Set output metadata to 96 DPI
const data = await sharp(input)
  .withMetadata({ density: 96 })
  .toBuffer();
```

Npm module: [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp)